# Could Data toggle be run on error or wrong input?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I am using java-script bootstrap. And i am trying make Modal to appear on error or wrong input. Is it possible? Button one on their website works perfect but can you modify it?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

I'd recommend creating a function that is run when the buttn in the modal is clicked to submit the input.

Example:

`<button onclick="checkInput()">Button</button>`

then create a function like the one below

```
// Pure JS
function checkInput () {
  if(document.getElementById('inputId').value == "correct input") {

    var modal = document.getElementById("modalId");
    modal.className = modal.className + " hide";

  }
}

//JQuery
function checkInput () {
  if($('#inputId').val() == "correct input") {
    $('#modalId').modal('toggle');
  }
}
```

Comment: Tnx it worked Fix on Click not on Lick :) ? or is it for touch screen functionality.

Comment: whoops! Sorry about that, I will correct that now. I am glad it helped!